# Plotting boxplots with categorial variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a dataframe with multiple dummy variables, min example would be:

```
 dict1 = [{'var0': '0.2','var1': '0','var2': '1'},
 {'var0': '0.4','var1': '1','var2': '1'},
 {'var0': '0.2', 'var1': '1','var2': '0'},
 {'var0': '0.4','var1': '1','var2': '0'},
 {'var0': '0.1','var1': '1','var2': '0'},
 {'var0': '0.6','var1': '0','var2': '0'}]
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

I would like to create a boxplot graph with a boxplot for each of the dummies on the x axis. The usual examples I found online consisted of 1 single categorical variable that took multiple values (say day of the week):

```
 sns.catplot(x="day", y="total_bill", kind="box", data=tips);
```

I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
 sns.catplot(x="var1, var2", y="var0", kind="box", data=df1);
```

Can anyone suggest an approach to do so? I was thinking to merge the dummies into 1 variable, but the problem is, they take the value 1 at the same time (so this is not like the day of the week situation). I appreciate any help.

Another option I thought of was to multiple var0 with each dummy and save the results as 2 new variables: var0var1 and var0var2. Then replace the 0s with NaN and then simply plot both by doing this (granted not a very pythonic approach):

```
 sns.boxplot(data=df1[['var0var1','var0var2']])
```

Comment: The only explanation of what you are trying to do seems to lie in the string `"var1, var2"`, which is obviously not working and hence not understandable. Try to explain it starting from the plot: What should the content of the plot be and why is it not possible to obtain this desired plot with the means you know of.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was not aware that this was not clear. I was actually able to figure it our myself using the approach I described at the bottom section.